# cycle identification for groups depending on column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data structure for n firms. Date, firm id, and some variable. The column cycle is what I expect. Note that always you have a positive number (could be negative), followed by some unknown amount of zeroes. The idea is to assign cycles (desired output) as shown in the table.

| DATE | firm | var | cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 14 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

So far I tried the following in R using dplyr:

```
    data <- data %>% 
      dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(some_tmp_var = ifelse(some_var!=0,1,0)) %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(firm) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(grp = rleid(some_tmp_var )) %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(firm, grp)%>%
      dplyr::group_indices(firm, grp,some_tmp_var ==1)
```

But, the result is a cycle by changes in the variable `some_tmp_var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>% 
  mutate(cyc = cumsum(+(sign(var) != lag(sign(var), default = 0) & sign(var) != 0)))

#> # A tibble: 13 x 5
#> # Groups:   firm [1]
#>     DATE  firm   var cycle   cyc
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1     2     1     1
#>  2     2     1     3     1     1
#>  3     3     1     4     1     1
#>  4     4     1     0     1     1
#>  5     5     1     0     1     1
#>  6     6     1     3     2     2
#>  7     7     1     4     2     2
#>  8     8     1     5     2     2
#>  9     9     1     7     2     2
#> 10    11     1     0     2     2
#> 11    12     1     0     2     2
#> 12    13     1     1     3     3
#> 13    14     1     2     3     3
```

#### Data:

```
read.table(text = "DATE     firm    var     cycle
1   1   2   1
2   1   3   1
3   1   4   1
4   1   0   1
5   1   0   1
6   1   3   2
7   1   4   2
8   1   5   2
9   1   7   2
11  1   0   2
12  1   0   2
13  1   1   3
14  1   2   3", header = T) -> data
```